# Java UDP Code in MATLAB

Tags: java, matlab, sockets, udp, multicast

I would like to run Java code in Matlab which deals with the Multicast UDP sockets.

The code is as follows:

```
socket = java.net.MultiSocket(streamPort);
socket.joinGroup(java.net.InetAddress.getByName(streamIP));
socket.setReuseAddress(1);

packet = java.net.DatagramPacket(zeros(1, intmax('uint16'), 'int8'), intmax('uint16'));

socket.receive(packet);

socket.leaveGroup(InetAddress.getByName(streamIP));
socket.close;

msg = packet.getData;
msg = msg(1:packet.getLength);
```

However, I get an error:

> Error variable or class `java.net.MultiSocket` not found

Could someone help me how to run this exactly in Matlab?

Comment: did you include the java.net.MultiSocket library? You need to add the class path using something like `javaclasspath` http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/javaclasspath.html

Comment: Please learn how to format code properly.  Just type out the code normally, highlight it all then use Ctrl + K or Cmd + K depending on what operating system you're using.